# you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, loader, unexpected-token

I m trying to go this script

`$(document).ready(() => { $('.iqdropdown').iqDropdown({ [options] }); });`

[image]

this is a Jquery plugin item-quantity-dropdown jQuery plugin (https://github.com/reservamos/item-quantity-dropdown#javascript),
and this code was written on instruction to this Plugin

[image]

but cmd write to me this

`ERROR in ./src/scripts/index.js 169:42 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (169:42) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See htt://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders`

But i have TS-loader (my WebPack config)

`const { CheckerPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader');`

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.pug$/,
    use: [
      'pug-loader'
    ]
  },

  {
    test: /\.scss|css$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    enforce: 'pre',
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'eslint-loader'
  },  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    loader: 'ts-loader',
    exclude: /(node_modules)/
  },
```

and i change target in my tsconfig to es2020

```
"module": "commonjs",
"target": "es2020",
"outDir": "./dist",
"lib": ["es2016", "dom"]`|
```

I try to change lib to es2020 too, but it gave nothing)

I have TypeScript v. 4

What can i do without installing a babel? Help please )

Comment: Have you tried setting `target` to `es5`?

Comment: yes, it was es5 before

Comment: What's on line 169

Comment: Oh sorry, i attached now a picture oh this

Comment: `{ [options] }` is invalid syntax, and is probably the cause of the error

Comment: what is that line supposed to do?

Comment: It is a juery plugin, I edited my post right now, look please.

Comment: in docs it's a common convention to mark something as optional by wrapping it with square brackets. I'm guessing that's what they mean, since this is invalid syntax. Try the method call with no arguments: `$('.iqdropdown').iqDropdown();` and see if that works

Comment: It's unfortunate they used the convention in a code snippet instead of in comments or text. They really should only put valid working code in code snippets.

Comment: God! `$('.iqdropdown').iqDropdown();` works! Now please can you tell me how i need to write my options inside this function?

Comment: you pass an object with the options as a parameter: `$('.iqdropdown').iqDropdown({ maxItems: 10 });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is done. Fred Stark (https://stackoverflow.com/users/992964/fred-stark)
helped me in comments:

> in docs it's a common convention to mark something as optional by
> wrapping it with square brackets. I'm guessing that's what they mean,
> since this is invalid syntax. Try the method call with no arguments:
> $('.iqdropdown').iqDropdown(); and see if that works – Fred Stark 13
> hours ago
>
> It's unfortunate they used the convention in a code snippet instead of
> in comments or text. They really should only put valid working code in
> code snippets. – Fred Stark 13 hours ago
>
> ​God! $('.iqdropdown').iqDropdown(); works! Now please can you tell me how i
> need to write my options inside this function? – Void0000 13 hours ago
>
> you pass an object with the options as a parameter:
> $('.iqdropdown').iqDropdown({ maxItems: 10 }); – Fred Stark 13 hours
> ago